# How to Add Animation in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation

i am applying animation in android listview. But it is working only the first row of the listview. it doesn't work on the whole listview. Can anyone please help me?

**MY Code is Below**

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_in_top);

animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

  public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    upcoming_list.setPressed(true);
    upcoming_list.startAnimation(animation);
  }
});

upcoming_list.clearAnimation();
upcoming_list.startAnimation(animation);
```

**And My Animation XML**

```
<translate
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
    android:toYDelta="1" />
```

Comment: Have you tried in Adapter class ?

Comment: This might help. https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Comment: i am also trying in adapter class. please send a sample code.